# What to reply to a person saying "Good Morning" when my time zone is different?

Tags: time, greetings

When I'm talking to a person in opposite time zone and the person greets with "Good morning" or Good evening/afternoon as per his time, is it ok to reply "Good afternoon" (as per my time-zone) when he said "Good Morning", and similarly replying as per my time zone, at other times?

Comment: Depends on your relationship with the person. If you're not in thrall to them, remind them that you're in a different timezone, and would they care to take that into account when they speak to you. You yourself, of course, should take care *never* to be so thoughtless when you greet *them*. Play it safe by saying something like *"Hi! Nice to speak to you again!".

Comment: But I'm still voting to close. This is etiquette, not language.

Comment: I think this is off-topic (ie, not a question about    "* Usage, word choice, and grammar
    * Etymology (history of words’ development)
    * Dialect differences
    * Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
    * Spelling and punctuation
    * Problems encountered by people learning English" (topics listed in [faq](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq))) and suggest asking in [meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/) regarding where to ask about where to ask it instead.

Comment: It would probably fit on [Culture exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17087/culture-exchange) stil on commitment on Area51.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open. This site has lots of greetings-related questions and language and etiquette are not completely separate ideas.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: If the precise choice of *language* were an issue here, I might agree. But it's really just a straightforward question about politeness in relation to whether and how you acknowledge a timezone difference, for which the answers should be the same in any language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're correct that this is etiquette and not specifically about English, but when I think about it, I wonder how common is talking to someone in an opposite time zone in a language other than english is? Sure you could, but English being such a common international language, it's a day to day affair for so many people. But that's just my opinion - a non-native English speaker.

Comment: @Atul Goyal: I don't see why the possibility of this etiquette issue particularly involving Anglophones makes it any more suitable for ELU. We probably have a higher percentage of Scrabble players than speakers of most/all other languages, but we don't discuss that here.

Comment: Not exact duplicate, not inappropriate/ objectionable -- therefore, should have been migrated somewhere. That puts the controversy to rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person saying the greeting is wishing something good for the other.

So if it's morning where you are, I should wish you a "good morning", regardless of my local timezone.

Likewise, if it's afternoon where I am, you should wish me a "good afternoon", regardless of your local timezone.

However, if they're already greeted you but used the wrong part of day, it doesn't really matter, the intention is the same. I would still reply with the appropriate greeting for their local timezone.

Answer (score 4):

If someone greets you according to their time zone like good morning/evening/afternoon, I think we should wish them the same, rather than explaining them the time zone difference. These would also make them feel comfortable that there is no gap between you people.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on formal terms with the other person, it would be appropriate and necessary to respond with "*Good* morning". The idea is to respect his gesture of wishing you, in the first place, rather than distracting from it. Also note the pronunciation, your stress will be on *Good*, to show that you care more about that part of the greeting :).

I believe this may also apply in an informal case, though I am not sure.